# How to make nice list of item IDs arranged in colums?

Tags: lists, tabbing

I would like to make a list of IDs or whatever properties of items in different groups. It should look like this:

```
Article group 1

Article 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ID

Second article  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ID



Group 2                    Cat No 1           Cat No 2

Product . . . . . . . . . . . ID1 . . . . . . . . ID2

Another product . . . . . . . ID1 . . . . . . . . ID2


Article group 3                                Cat No

Something . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ID

Other thing . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ID
```

I tried to do it in tabbing environments. It works if I don't use the leading dots but \dotfill doesn't work in tabbing environment.

I also tried to use list environment, but I don't know how to align the ID columns correctly.

This is what I did:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Article group 1
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Article 1~\dotfill~ID
\item Second article~\dotfill~ID
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Group 2
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Product~\dotfill~ID1~\dotfill~ID2
\item Another product~\dotfill~ID1~\dotfill~ID2
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Article group 3~\hfill~Cat No
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Something~\dotfill~ID
\item Other thing~\dotfill~ID
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

The columns are not aligned correctly.
I thought making it in table/tabular but cell I can't use \dotfill either in a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example defines macros `\dotsfrom` and `\dotsto`, which put a dotted line between the locations. The locations are get from module `zref-savepos` of package `zref`, which provides an interface for the `\pdfsavepos` feature of pdfTeX, which is also available in LuaTeX and XeTeX.
The first LaTeX run stores the positions in the `.aux` file as references and the next run will use the position values from the previous run. This requires two LaTeX runs.

The table is implemented by a simple `tabular*` for the whole line width and with glue between the columns to fill the space.
The setting of the dots via `\dotsfrom` and `\dotsto` would also
work in a `tabbing` environment or in lists.

The dotted line uses the code of `\@dottedtocline`, which is used in the table of contents, for two reasons:

- The space between the dots is not as narrow as in `\dotfill` and therefore less obtrusive. Also the space can be configured by redefining `\@dotsep`.
- The code uses `\leaders` instead of `\cleaders` (`\dotfill`). Therefore
  the dots are vertically aligned if they are in the same enclosing box.
  However, this is not true here. Therefore, all enclosing boxes for the dots are starting vertically aligned at *x* coordinate zero.

The example shows the technique. But I have not wrapped the low level macros inside markup commands, because the target layout is not too clear
(alignment requirements, what about too long entries, how many categories, may the article name column use space of unused category columns, are the article groups independent with possible different positions for the middle column, multi-page tables, ...?).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\providecommand{\zsaveposx}{\zsavepos}

\newcounter{dotsfromto}
\renewcommand*{\thedotsfromto}{DFT@\the\value{dotsfromto}}
\newcommand*{\dotsfrom}{%
  \stepcounter{dotsfromto}%
  \leavevmode
  \zsaveposx{\thedotsfromto f}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dotsto}{%
  \leavevmode
  \zsaveposx{\thedotsfromto t}%
  \zref@refused{\thedotsfromto f}%
  \zref@refused{\thedotsfromto t}%
  \ifnum\zposx{\thedotsfromto t}>\zposx{\thedotsfromto f}\relax
    \llap{%
      \hbox to \zposx{\thedotsfromto t}sp{%
        \kern\zposx{\thedotsfromto f}sp\relax
        \leaders\hbox{$\m@th % from \@dottedtocline
          \mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu%
        $}\hfill
      }%
    }%  
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcc@{}}
  \bfseries Article group 1 & & Cat.~No.\\
  Article 1\dotsfrom & & \dotsto ID\\
  Second article\dotsfrom & &\dotsto ID\\[\normalbaselineskip]
  \bfseries Group 2 & Cat.~No.~1 & Cat.~No.~2\\
  Product\dotsfrom & \dotsto ID1\dotsfrom & \dotsto ID2\\
  Another product\dotsfrom & \dotsto ID1\dotsfrom & \dotsto ID2
  \\[\normalbaselineskip]
  \bfseries Article group 3 & & Cat.~No.\\
  Something\dotsfrom &  & \dotsto ID\\
  Other thing\dotsfrom & & \dotsto ID\\
  \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Very impressive. Unfortunately in my output the dots are missing.  There are warnings saying "LaTeX Warning: Reference `DFT@1f' on page 1 undefined on input line 35." How can I fix this?

Comment: @bcsikos As I have written in the answer, you need at least *two* LaTeX runs.

Comment: Sorry for the noise! I forgot the second latex run.

Comment: Is there any way to place the dots exactly below/above each other? In Article group 3 part of the example the dots in the 2 rows alternate, would be nicer placed exactly below each other.

Comment: @bcsikos Thanks for noticing. It was quite surprised, because I didn't realize that the feature of `\leaders` also depends on the enclosing box. The answer is now fixed by starting the boxes at the same *x* coordinate.

Comment: Excellent! Now it looks professional. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using full-width tabulars - in the form of [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) - would work for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}X<{\dotfill}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Article group 1
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Article 1~\dotfill~ID
\item Second article~\dotfill~ID
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Group 2
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Product~\dotfill~ID1~\dotfill~ID2
\item Another product~\dotfill~ID1~\dotfill~ID2
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Article group 3~\hfill~Cat No
\end{list}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Something~\dotfill~ID
\item Other thing~\dotfill~ID
\end{list}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ L L r@{} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Article group 1} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{L}{Article 1} & ID \\
  \multicolumn{2}{L}{Second article} & ID \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ L L r@{} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Group 2} \\
  \midrule
  Product         & ID1 & ID2 \\
  Another product & ID1 & ID2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ L L r@{} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Article group 3} & \llap{Cat No} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{L}{Something} & ID \\
  \multicolumn{2}{L}{Other thing} & ID \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The horizontal rules are just for show from [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Note that these structures won't break across the page boundary, whereas your `list`s would.